# How can I Build my code in codeblocks?the Codeblocks IDE is stopped working

Tags: c, codeblocks

I installed codeblocks and then I wrote a code, but when I press the build key the codeblocks IDE is stopped working.

And then the program closes.

What shoud I do?

Comment: Your question leaves a lot to guessing. Please provide more context. Try to provide all the info which e.g. the answer below is guessing about. Which OS? Which compiler? Which CodeBlocks version? How did you install? How did you configure the compiler? Can you use the intended compiler directly (i.e. by using it from commandline)? What manual did you read and follow for setting up your IDE? In which way does "IDE is stopped working"? Crash? Hang? Bluescreen? Any helpful error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any build messages?

I guess maybe you should check your compiler setting.

Settings -> Compiler -> Toolchain executables

[image]

Make sure the path of MinGW is correctly set.

(Or maybe you should install MinGW first, download link: https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/)

Comment: Daring and brave answer, based on guessing... I can see that you will use your commenting privilege to good benefit as soon as you have it. Good luck.

Comment: Maryam, please give more information. See my comment on your question.